# Deleting files in Pythonic way

Tags: python-2.7

I want to delete some files from the file system. I get a list having absolute  path of files and logic is to remove the found files and print their name.

Logic i have written is as follows, this removes the found file in `temp_list` but does not print their name.

```
log.info("Files removed [%s]", [os.remove(f) for f in temp_list if os.path.exists(f)])
```

Output is `[None, None..]`.

Can i modify the statement so that the files are removed and removed files are printed too in a single statement?

Comment: Using a list comprehension for side effects is generally bad practice, but you could do `[f for f in temp_list if os.path.exists(f) and os.remove(f) is None]`

Comment: @tobias_k it needs to be something truth-y for the filtering condition to include `f` in the output; you could save a few characters with `not`, I suppose.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are right, did not think of that.

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k for your response and editing.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe for your response. Could you please elaborate more on " you could save a few characters with not".

Comment: @tobias_k , is this usage an example of "list comprehension for side effect".  As i need resultant list (of files actually found in file system), which i am logging via a trace. I am very new to Python and on first reading of your response could not understand the point you mentioned. Could you please enlighten.

Comment: @user3273016 as in `not os.remove(f)` rather than `os.remove(f) is None`. Yes, this is using a list comprehension for a side effect; there is no reason to do it in a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i modify the statement so that the files are removed and removed files are printed too in a single statement?

Yes, you can, as pointed out by @jonrsharpe, by putting the actual call to `remove` into the condition part of the list comprehension

```
log.info("Files removed [%s]", [f for f in temp_list if os.path.exists(f) and os.remove(f) is None])
```

However, while this removes and prints the files in a single line, it is not considered "pythonic", or good practice, for at least two reasons:

1. Using methods inside list comprehensions for their side effects is generally bad practice. Consider what happens if you decide that you no longer need that log statement and comment or remove the line!
2. In this particular case, the list comprehension's condition is pretty counter-intuitive, as well, as you need to negate the "result" of `remove` to make it "truthy", by doing either `and os.remove(f) is None` or (even worse) `and not os.remove(f)`.

Instead, I suggest you do something like this:

```
files_to_remove = [f for f in temp_list if os.path.exists(f)]
for f in files_to_remove:
    os.remove(f)
log.info("Files removed [%s]", files_to_remove)
```

This may be more lines of code, but it's easier to understand and could thus be considered more "pythonic".